# How to upload deb file to official apt repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, deb, aptitude

When I search with this question, I am getting only posts related to setting up our own repository completely.

But, I want to just upload my deb file to official ubuntu repository or debian repo so that apt install my_application

should work.

Could you please guide how to do that.

I tried many posts in serverfault but didn't get any related option, so posting here

Comment: Neither Debian nor Ubuntu permit pre-compiled debs to be uploaded by random folks from the internet. That would be a big security hole. First you join the organization and build trust. Then you contribute source code. Then they build the code into a package on their build system.

Comment: I think PPA's are what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

You have to be approved to upload to the official repositories.  This allows a level of trust to be established between the maintainers and users of the packages on the system.

On top of that, it is unlikely you actually *want* to do this, because it would require a whole set of requirements and you'd have to learn to properly maintain your software and packages.

Instead, you can create your own repository, and those who trust you (ie: you yourself) can add the repository to their system and pull in your packages.  These are referred to as Personal Package Archives, or PPAs, and [Launchpad offers such a service](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas).

Even if your end goal is to have your software in the official repositories, this will get you started learning how to package and maintain properly until your software is shown to be wanted in the official ecosystem.  Or, you can use the PPA forever and not worry about anything else.